# Name 'total' is not defined when trying to sum using a for-loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I am trying to sum this list using a for-loop instead of the sum function, but it keeps telling me that the name is not defined.

```
monthly_sales = [500, 600, 600, 500, 200, 700, 500, 100, 100, 600]
for sales_value in monthly_sales:
    total = total + sales_value

print("Total in annual sales is $", total)
```

I expect the output to provide one line saying "Total in annual sales is $4400."

Comment: You didn;t declare (initialize) *total*, but you are using it. Add `total = 0` before the *for* loop. Or everything in one line: `print("Total in annual sales is $", sum(monthly_sales))`.

Comment: What do you expect `total` to be when you encounter `total = total + sales_value` the first time?

Comment: If you do not define total before, python does not know what to use as first value (i.e. the first time you go through the loop)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, you just have to initialize the variable before referring to it inside the loop:

```
total = 0
```

We can also write a more pythonic solution like this:

```
total = sum(monthly_sales)
```

Comment: Thanks!  I typically use the sum function, but needed to test an alternative method.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare total=0 before, you can also change total = total + value for:

```
total += value
```

.

```
monthly_sales = [500, 600, 600, 500, 200, 700, 500, 100, 100, 600]

total = 0
for sales_value in monthly_sales:
    total += sales_value

print("Total in annual sales is $", total)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate total before you do total += x